# Why does HAProxy recommend setting timeouts that are multiples of 3 seconds?

Tags: tcp, haproxy

From the [HAProxy documentation on client timeouts](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#4-timeout%20connect):

> It is a good practice to cover one or several TCP packet losses by
>   specifying timeouts that are slightly above multiples of 3 seconds
>   (eg: 4 or 5 seconds).

That seems like an arbitrary number. What is the significance of the 3 second figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this is the default TCP retransmission timeout. From [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/169292):

> TCP starts a re-transmission timer when each outbound segment is
>   handed down to IP. If no acknowledgment has been received for the data
>   in a given segment before the timer expires, then the segment is
>   retransmitted, up to the TcpMaxDataRetransmissions times. The default
>   value for this parameter is 5.
>
> The re-transmission timer is initialized to 3 seconds when a TCP
>   connection is established; however it is adjusted "on the fly" to
>   match the characteristics of the connection using Smoothed Round Trip
>   Time (SRTT) calculations as described in RFC793. The timer for a given
>   segment is doubled after each re-transmission of that segment. Using
>   this algorithm, TCP tunes itself to the "normal" delay of a
>   connection. TCP connections over high-delay links will take much
>   longer to time out than those over low- delay links.